# Build android widget and display data that is in localStorage of an app

Tags: android, cordova, android-widget, local-storage

I have a webapp with Cordova (ex PhoneGap) running on Android. What I would like to do now is to create a Widget and load some data that is stored in localStorage of the webApp. Is that possible?
Thanks!